# Specifying the appropriate index using a conditional expression in a 2D array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

In each row of a 2D array, I want to assign 10 to the elements in columns 0 and 2 if the 0th element is less than 4.

```python
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
arr[(arr[:,0] < 4), [0,2]] = 10
print(arr)
```

Actual result

```
[[10  1  2]
 [ 3  4 10]]
```

Expected result

```
[[10  1  10]
 [10  4  10]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the array slightly bigger to make the problem more interesting.

```
In [134]: arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3); arr
Out[134]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Your row select, as boolean and index:

```
In [135]: (arr[:,0] < 4)
Out[135]: array([ True,  True, False])    
In [136]: np.nonzero((arr[:,0] < 4))
Out[136]: (array([0, 1]),)
```

If we just 2 two lists (or array) (of the same size); we index the "diagonal".  That's what you are getting.

```
In [137]: arr[[0,1],[0,2]]
Out[137]: array([0, 5])
```

To get the block, or 4 corners, the 'row' index has to (2,1) shape:

```
In [138]: arr[[[0],[1]],[0,2]]
Out[138]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [3, 5]])
```

A (2,1) array `broadcasts` with a (2,) to select as (2,2) block.

We can't just make the expand the boolean mask to 2d.  But we can make the equivalent pair of arrays with `np.ix_`:

```
In [140]: I,J = np.ix_((arr[:,0]<4), [0,2]); I,J
Out[140]: 
(array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[0, 2]]))
```

And then use those to index `arr`:

```
In [141]: arr[I,J] = 10    
In [142]: arr
Out[142]: 
array([[10,  1, 10],
       [10,  4, 10],
       [ 6,  7,  8]])
```

Comment: Your explanations were very clear!
Thank you for teaching me!